# Inconsistent download info from university website

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

For more than an hour, I have unsuccessfully tried to download the PDF displayed at http://diposit.ub.edu/dspace/handle/2445/99521.

The URL seems to be http://diposit.ub.edu/dspace/bitstream/2445/99521/1/MFGV_PhD_THESIS.pdf.

I tried both Safari, Firefox and Google Chrome, and all three not only fail to download, but in fact print erratic and inconsistent info about the download management itself : the actually downloaded data varies in zigzags, instead of continually increasing as in a normal download.

Any ideas (apart from directly asking the university) appreciated.

Comment: Okay for me, Firefox. Downloaded file using the button. No sure what to suggest. What OS are you on?

Comment: I would contact the university support. Otherwise make sure your internet is fine. Also try downloading files from other sources to see if they work. If it is solely the university pdf, then there must be something happening on their end.

Comment: Try this on Google : **`insite:http://diposit.ub.edu inurl:"MFGV_PhD_THESIS.pdf"`** and click the link you get.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus worked for me, thanks a lot ! If you put your comment in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in Comments, Try this :

```
insite:http://diposit.ub.edu inurl:"MFGV_PhD_THESIS.pdf"
```

#### How it works.

This is basically a **[Google Dork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_hacking)**. In simpler terms, using advanced operators to search for particular keywords. I have used here two advanced operators :

- insite : your://sitename/here

  ```
  insite:http://diposit.ub.edu
  ```

  That asks google to search for keywords **`only` in this site** that is University's website. And What to search is :
- inurl : "Keyword in quotes"

  ```
  inurl:"MFGV_PhD_THESIS.pdf"
  ```

  Look for keyword `MFGV_PhD_THESIS.pdf` in the URLs.

So, when combined both, It says look for `MFGV_PhD_THESIS.pdf` word in all webpage URLs of site `http://diposit.ub.edu`.

You may also use `filetype:pdf` Dork, but I'll leave it to you as an exercise. To quickly learn some Google dorks, Visit [this blog on Cybrary](https://www.cybrary.it/0p3n/advanced-google-dorking-commands/).

Feel free to add-in more details.